# Socket async sending and receiving data

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I am working on a software that sends and receives data from/to lots of sockets. It is highly asynchronous and for that reason I am worried about the following scenario: N threads trying to send data to the same socket. This is, N threads invoking BeginSend at the same time.

**Clarification**: I am not using threads but the 'system' does it. That´s what the documentation says: "*When your application calls BeginSend, the system will use a separate thread to execute the specified callback method*"

I´ve done this test to know if it fails with SocketException, or not (because i cannot find documentation about that):

```
    [Test]
    public void DoIt2()
    {
        var byteCount = 0;
        var manualEvents = new[] { new ManualResetEvent(false), new ManualResetEvent(false), new ManualResetEvent(false) };
        var message = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        var callback = new AsyncCallback(ar =>{
            var resetEvent = (ManualResetEvent)ar.AsyncState;
            Interlocked.Add(ref byteCount,  socket.EndSend(ar));
            resetEvent.Set();
        });

        socket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8000);
        socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, callback, manualEvents[0]);
        socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, callback, manualEvents[1]);
        socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, callback, manualEvents[2]);

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(manualEvents);

        socket.Close();
        Assert.AreEqual(12, byteCount);
    }
```

It passed green. However, I need to know if there is something wrong on it. Is it safe to assume BeginSend/BeginReceive can be called multiple times before EndSend/EndReceive are called? I mean, is the following pattern okey?

1. BeginSend
2. BeginSend
3. BeginSend
4. EndSend
5. EndSend
6. EndSend

What about the arrival data order? I know this is TCP but my question is, given BeginSend is async, will data sent from 1 arrives before 2 and 3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the specifics of .NET socket object, but In general sending from different threads to the same socket is not a good idea.  The data sent on the socket could be in any order and would most likely violate the protocol on that socket.

Comment: The point is I am not using threads but the 'system' does it. That´s what documentation says: "When your application calls BeginSend, the system will use a separate thread to execute the specified callback method". I assume the 'system' is the OS. I will update my question to let that clear. Thank you

Comment: My apologies. I know the OS will do it in the order you send it, if the .NET class is a wrapper around this what you are doing is fine. The OS does not use a different thread for each send request.

Comment: Interpretting your clarification I suspect the class is using IO completion at the OS level.  What this is saying is that the callback will be from a different thread to the one you called the BeginSend on - there is, however, only one extra thread involved.  So long as your callback is thread safe all should be well.

Comment: Oh, I see. It means my three BeginSend calls enqueue three 'jobs' in the OS and then, the OS does its job asynchronously (in the requested order) and invokes my callback (using the IO completion feature) in the correct order too. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes that is what happens at the OS level.